# Jekyll dynamic navigation hash links

Tags: dynamic, hash, navigation, jekyll

I use the following loop to generate a dynamic navigation for my Jekyll based site. This works as expected. Theres just one thing which doesn't work. Jekyll/Liquid ignores 'current' if the link contains a hash in the url for a internal hash link on the same page like so: `/about/#me`.
Is there any way to make that loop work for this links as well?

```
        {% for link in site.navigation %}
            {% assign current = nil %}
            {% if page.url contains link.url %}
                {% assign current = 'current' %}
            {% endif %}
            <li class="nav-list-item {{ current }}">
                <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can revert you test :

```
{% if link.url contains page.url %}
    {% assign current = 'current' %}
{% endif %}
```